# Best possible approximation of P(X,Y)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory

I want to show that $\min_Q D(P_{Y|X} || Q | P_x) = I(X;Y)$ and I've arrived at a question. Here $D$ is the KL divergence or relative entropy and $I$ is of course the mutual information.

Algebra-wrestled with it a bit and found I want to find Q such that the following is minimized:

$\sum_{x,y}P(x,y)\log \frac{P(x,y)}{P(x)Q(y)}$

Now: this is always positive I think, so I'd prefer to set $Q = P(y|x)$ to make the whole thing zero. But I can't condition on $x$ so I'd like to approximate $P(x,y)$ as closely as possible. Is this always done with $P(x)P(y)$, given no information on correlation between $X$ and $Y$? It makes intuitive sense, but I'd prefer a slightly more convincing argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to minimise on $Q$, why don't you simply expand the term in the log and minimize the part that depends on $Q(y)$ with the constraint $\sum Q(y) = 1$.

Result should be more convincing that playing with intuitive arguments (which may be true as well as misleading).

Comment: Well to me it seems that the insight that the distribution minimizing distance to $p(x,y)$ is given by the product of the marginals would be more illuminating than answering this specific question.

Comment: I guess it is a matter of thinking style: whether the intuition should confirm the maths or the opposite.

Comment: There's nothing non-rigorous about the argument though, clearly the term is minimized when we find a distribution that best approximates $P(x,y)$. What your method would do is to prove exactly that, but I'm guessing it's a very round-about way to do prove it.

Comment: Well, write the [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) here : $L = -\sum_{x,y} P(x,y) \ln Q(y) - \lambda(\sum_y Q(y) - 1)$, and compute $\partial L/\partial Q(y) = 0$. It's quite straight-forward. (Spoiler: the result is $Q^*(y) = P(y)$).

Comment: Yeah I admit, that turns out to be a lot easier than it seemed at first. Thanks!